# Creating a function that outputs a series of 2 by 2 tables

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create a function that lets me output a series of two by two tables using a large number of variables. I have created the function, but the outcome is not what I expected. Instead of doing the crosstab for each category between the variables, the function does a two by two of the full variables. Can anyone help me with this?

```
# get package to create function for 2by2 table
install.packages("descr")

# make dummy data 
dummy <-data.frame(city = sample(c("SF", "AR", "NYC","MN"),13000,replace = TRUE),
                   city_2 = sample(c("SF", "AR", "NYC","MN"),13000,replace = TRUE),
                   year = sample(as.factor(c(1990, 2000, 1999, 1989)),13000,replace = TRUE)
)


# create crosstab function
crosstab_func <- function(x, y) {
  out <-  descr::crosstab(x, y,
                          chisq = T,
                          prop.c = F, prop.r = T, plot = F,
                          digits = 1)
  return(out)
}

# select vars for use
vars <- c("dummy$city", "dummy$city_2", "dummy$year")

# use function
crosstab_func(vars, vars)
```

This is what one of the outputs should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the column names to the function along with data.

```
crosstab_func <- function(data, x, y) {
  out <-  descr::crosstab(data[[x]], data[[y]],
                          chisq = T,
                          prop.c = F, prop.r = T, plot = F,
                          digits = 1)
  out$RowData <- x
  out$ColData <- y
  return(out)
}
```

This returns :

```
crosstab_func(dummy, 'city', 'city_2')

  Cell Contents 
|-------------------------|
|                   Count | 
|             Row Percent | 
|-------------------------|

==============================================
          city_2
city  AR      MN     NYC      SF   Total
----------------------------------------------
AR        741     834     804     804    3183 
         23.3%   26.2%   25.3%   25.3%   24.5%
----------------------------------------------
MN        831     815     856     790    3292 
         25.2%   24.8%   26.0%   24.0%   25.3%
----------------------------------------------
NYC       792     784     851     812    3239 
         24.5%   24.2%   26.3%   25.1%   24.9%
----------------------------------------------
SF        787     810     840     849    3286 
         24.0%   24.7%   25.6%   25.8%   25.3%
----------------------------------------------
Total    3151    3243    3351    3255   13000 
==============================================

Statistics for All Table Factors

Pearson's Chi-squared test 
------------------------------------------------------------
Chi^2 = 8.726605      d.f. = 9      p = 0.5 

        Minimum expected frequency: 771.5102
```

To perform this for every combination of column names use `combn` :

```
result <- combn(names(dummy), 2, function(x) 
                crosstab_func(dummy, x[1], x[2]), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: how about for a list of variables? So I want the function to do city vs city_2, city vs year, city_2 vs year.

Comment: We can use `combn` to run this for every combination of column names. See updated answer.

Comment: I am currently struggling to retain the names of the labels (or even the names of the variables) when I use the function. Any suggestions on this??

Comment: I have changed the function to get you the correct label names. Can you check the updated answer @MohamedYusuf ?